# Moving jenkins from VM to Kube, error with hudson

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I'm moving jenkins, sonarqube and nexus from vms to kube cluster, all is set up, but when I moved the jobs I get the error in Manage Jenkins

```
CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.buildblocker.BuildBlockerProperty
```

```
CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty, CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.buildblocker.BuildBlockerProperty
```

```
CannotResolveClassException: com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger, CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty, CannotResolveClassException: hudson.plugins.buildblocker.BuildBlockerProperty
```

it says it's **unreadable data** and suggests to discard it otherwise it will be just ignored - and this error is basically in every job  - any ideas of the cause/solution? Is it maybe issue of plugin ? I didn't see anything related to that in prev jenkins or in plugins list.

PS: I installed jenkins with same version as the one on vm

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved new Jenkins was missing 3 plugins in the helm values file:

```
  installPlugins:
...
    - build-blocker-plugin
    - job-dsl
    - parameterized-scheduler
```